# Why can't ethoxide ion act as nucleophile?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, nucleophilic-substitution, elimination, nucleophilicity

Consider the reaction of chlorocyclohexane with ethoxide in a suitable inert solvent. The major product according to my textbook is cyclohexene, which implies E2 reaction pathway. Why not S<sub>N</sub>2?

$\ce{EtO^-}$ is an unstable anion, so why can it act as nucleophile rather than acting as a base?

Comment: Ethoxide is a bulky species. So it would undergo elimination rather than substitution. Perhaps you might get a better insight to this by [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15728/why-does-alcoholic-koh-prefer-elimination-whereas-aqueous-koh-prefers-substituti).

Comment: @Proscionexium Then what about $\ce{NH_2^-}$? It also prefer elimination to above compound, this time it isn't bulkier.

Comment: Are you talking about $\ce{R-NH_2^-}$ or just only $\ce{NH_2^-}$?

Comment: @Proscionexium just $\ce{NH2-}$

Comment: I think maybe because abstracting $\ce{H^+}$ by $\ce{NH_2^-}$ would also release $\ce{Cl^-}$ (forming cyclohexene) just as $\ce{Cl^-}$ could be released by substitution (but remaining only cyclohexane).

Comment: @Proscionexium But $\ce{ \Delta H}$ whould be higher for elimination (Removing two $\sigma$ bonds). Also $\ce{EtO-}$ should be a good nucleophile due to its unstablity.

Comment: SN2 does occur. What do you think the minor product is?

Comment: @Proscionexium It's not bulky - compare with t-butanolate that actually is.

Comment: @Waylander I mean why not major product  by SN2.

Comment: @Leibniz-Z  There is enough hindrance of SN2 by the cyclohexane ring to favour proton abstraction by ethoxide

Comment: @Waylander then according to you $\ce{NH2-},\ce{OH-}$ would guve major product according to SN2.

Comment: Not in the case of amide anion. It is a very much stronger base and likely to produce more elimination

Comment: @Waylander but why? Since $\ce{\Delta H}$ is higher for elimination. And what about hydroxide ion?

Answer (score -1):

Ethoxide acts as a base only in presence of $\beta$-hydrogens. For secondary and primary alkyl halides, usually, $\text{S}_\text{N}\text{2}$ is favored over $\text{E}_\text{2}$ mechanism.

$\text{E}_\text{2}$ mechanism does not occur in the absence of $\beta$-hydrogens:

[image: nucleophilic substitution of chloromethane in ethoxide]

$\text{S}_\text{N}\text{2}$ reaction is slow for secondary alkyl halides, further stearic hinderance is present due to the cyclic nature of **chlorocyclohexane**.

[image: substitution elimination chlorocyclohexane ethoxide nucleophile base]

#### Reference

1. Solomons, T. W. G., Fryhle, C. B. (2011). *Organic Chemistry*, *10th ed.* John Wiley & Sons.